What links a GCP service account to a YT channel ownership?
If I want to use a service account to upload videos to a YT channel.
Where in YT should I define this service account as a channel owner?
Otherwise, how is this linkage done?
An LLM bot said it's under "advance settings" but I found nothing.

The YouTube Data API supports service accounts only for YouTube content owners that own and manage multiple YouTube channels, such as record labels and movie studios. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps

Thanks, but this relates to "installed apps" only? Or websites as well?

The requirement is regarding your account (content owner) irrespective of what is accessing it. An important item to understand is that YouTube is not part of Google Cloud. A service account is an authorization identity (principal) of Google Cloud. Google has been slowly adding service account support to other Google services, but YouTube is not one of those services. You must design using User OAuth 2.0.

Thanks! For other services. Is there somehow penetration of the GCP owners permissions in other services? e.g a GCP owner has permission X to service Y thus the service account will have it too. Or the client secret encapsulates it too?

I don't understand your question. If you have a question about a particular Google service, specify the service while posting a new question. Service accounts are assigned IAM Roles as bindings to a Google Cloud resource such as a project. For Google services that do support service accounts, they use OAuth Scopes to grant permissions.
